# WFS GetFeature request with box failed on OGR datastore

Tags: geoserver, wfs, geotools, getfeature

I prepared an OGR datastore and imported features from a GeoJSON data set using REST.

If I now send a `wfs?request=GetFeature&bbox=.....`, I get an error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: PropertyDescriptor is null 
did you request a property that does not exist?
```

I traced it down to: [ComplexTypeImpl:70](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/feature/type/ComplexTypeImpl.java#L70) where an invalid property occurs.

This happens since an additional bogus attribute with `name=""` was added at: [OGRFeatureSource:213](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/ogr/ogr-core/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/ogr/OGRFeatureSource.java#L213) `Set<String> extraAttributeSet = ...`

Those extra attribute is extracted from the query filter which is a BBOXImpl. I guess the intention is to get "`the_geom`" for the filter envelope to apply on.

The BBOX of the query is generated by a geoserver class at: 
[BaseFeatureKvpRequestReader:354](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/wfs/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wfs/kvp/BaseFeatureKvpRequestReader.java#L354)

Here a comment suggests:

```
// JD: use "" so that it applies to all geometries
String name = "";
```

Seems that other data stores have no problem with this.

Any idea?

Comment: Name is a required attribute of gml

Comment: If you think it is a bug please raise it on the user list